# Buttons in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 buttons in my template, the first:

```
<button 
 [style.background-color]="service_rec.status == 
 'Online' ? 'green' : 'red'" class="btn btn-default">
              {{ service_rec.status }}
 </button>
```

And second:

```
<button *ngIf="!!service_rec.servicecontrolled" 
  [style.background-color]="service_rec.controlled == 
  'true' ? 'green' : 'orange'"
  class="btn btn-warning"
  (click)="onPost(service_rec.title, service_rec.status, service_rec.id)">
  {{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | toOnOff }}
</button>
```

Last button have pipe:

```
 @Pipe({ name: 'toOnOff' })
  export class OnOffPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: boolean): string {
    return (!!value) ? 'Stop' : 'false';
  }
}
```

And how to create a pipe, which able to create a `'Start'` (not `'Stop'`) button, when second button is `'Offline'` (not `'Online'`)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to provide parameters to pipes. Here is a sample:

```
{{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | toOnOff:'some value' }}
{{ service_rec.servicecontrolled | json | toOnOff:someProp }}
```

You'll be able then to get this value as parameter of the `transform` method of the pipe.